# Form filling in presentation mode in okular

Tags: pdf, okular

I have a beamer presentation with some animation. When I load the pdf, okular shows a "Show forms" option, on enabling that I am able to play those animations. However when I enter the presentation mode I am no longer able to play the animation. Instead clicking on it takes me to the next slide. Is it possible to show forms in presentation mode?